# Java HTTP library to request an OpenAPI token and issue Authorized requests

Tags: java

I need to perform a set of HTTP Operations which include a POST with Form Parameters and a GET using HTTP Headers to set the Authorization Header:

```
public void testResourceIsSecured() {
    String authResponse = ClientBuilder.newClient()
            .target("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/thorntail-cmd-client/protocol/openid-connect/token")
            .request()
            .post(Entity.form(new Form()
                    .param("grant_type", "password")
                    .param("client_id", "thorntail-cmd-client-example")
                    .param("username", "user1")
                    .param("password", "password1")
            ), String.class);
    String accessToken = getAccessTokenFromResponse(authResponse);

    String serviceResponse = ClientBuilder.newClient()
            .target("http://localhost:8080/mpjwt/secured")
            .request()
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + accessToken)
            .get(String.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("Hi user1, this resource is secured", serviceResponse);
}

private String getAccessTokenFromResponse(String response) {
    String tokenStart = response.substring("{\"access_token\":\"".length());
    return tokenStart.substring(0, tokenStart.indexOf("\""));
}
```

The above code works with Resteasy client API, though I'm not allowed to use this library because of the dependencies it brings in. Which Java HTTP library would you advice to use as replacement, which brings the least amount of dependencies in?
Thanks

Comment: Which dependencies aren't allowed?

Comment: It's out of the question scope. I'm just looking for a valid replacement of rest-easy client API with a plain Java library to perform the above requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [RestAssured](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/4.0.0). Not sure if it's dependencies fit better to your needs. It can be used to test API's and therefore it can be used as well as a simple REST client.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely the best replacement for resteasy client API. Pretty similar API and, having quarkus test libraries in my classpath it turns out I even got it out of the box.